# What does it mean when encode a yuv422 file to yuv420 by libx264 lossless encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I have an AVI file `input.avi` encoded in `HQ` which has `yuv422` format according to `ffprobe`.

Now, if I run the following command

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Will the `out.mp4` be lossless compared with `input.avi`? or it will be 'lossless' except half of the `U` and `V` information is lost?

Comment: No. Yes. You pretty much answered your own question in the last line.

Comment: BTW you can encode h.264 in yuv422, but not all players will play it

Comment: @stib Thanks! I want to calculate the PSNR and SSIM between `input.avi` and an encoded mp4 file. But the yuv format is different, so I am encoding the `input.avi` to 'lossless' yuv420p mp4, then calculate the PSNR and SSIM.

Comment: Just look at the SSIM score for the luma plane. U and V are not relevant in this case. Or you could downsample the AVI to 4:2:0 before passing it to the quality compare filters i.e. `[1]format=yuv420p[a];[0][a]psnr..`

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks! Would you please give a full command sample? I am new to `ffmpeg`, I am not sure how to add `[1]format=yuv420p[a];[0][a]psnr..` to my command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly compare the YUV422P AVI and YUV420P MP4,

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -i out.mp4
   -filter_complex
      "[0]format=yuv420p,split[avi-p][avi-s];
       [1][avi-p]psnr;[1][avi-s]ssim" -f null -
```

Comment: It gives an average value on the terminal, how can we output a log file with values of each frame?  I tried `-lavfi psnr="stats_file=psnr.log"` but no luck.